# How add a webview to a layout that have more widgets

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to add a webview to my layout.But that layout have few other widgets also.But when i run the application webview takes the entire screen and other widgets get disappear.here is my layout page.xml....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp" android:id="@+id/web"></WebView>

<View   android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="2px" android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" ></View>

<TextView android:text="Simple text view"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and in the activity class

```
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    WebView wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    wv1.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

It does not display the view and textView but webview get the entire screen.Please show me what i am doing wrong here.Or what is the correct way i should do.
thank you.

Comment: Here you can get the Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382188/how-to-set-webview-as-non-fullscreen

Comment: thanks Hossain, i think redirect make the problem as CommonsWare said there. google.com redirects to google.lk and then the browser make me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), it will solve your problem.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         WebView wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
         wv1.setWebViewClient(new myClient());
         wv1.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }

    class myClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your xml like this, then your textview vill be shown on the botton, the view will be shown above the textview, the webview will be shown in the rest spase.

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...
>
<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    ...
/>
<View
    android:layout_above="@id/sample_text"
    android:id="@+id/sample_view"
    ...
>
<WebView
    android:layout_above="@id/sample_view"
    ...
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```