# how to insert additional space into webview

Tags: android, webview

I have one `WebView` and one `LinearLayout`(called header) inside RelativeLayout.
My destination is, 
If I scroll up the webview, header will be scrolled up too as if they are merged. so i tried to insert additional space into webview, and to place header over that space.
But I can't know how to insert additional space into webview! Overriding `computeVerticalScrollRange(), computeVerticalScrollOffset(), computeVerticalScrollExtent(), onDraw(), onLayout(), onMeasure()` doesn't worked at all. I can't use html padding too, because when webview is scaled up or down, that padding is scaled together. How to do this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mail_read_scrollview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mail_read_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <SomeViews />
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:id="@+id/mail_read_contents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mail_read_title_box_padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mail_read_title_box_padding_left">

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi kindly post your xml design.

Comment: put linearlayouts inside, it can work like space

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo Thanks, but not works.

Comment: try to put android:weight inside that LinearLayouts

Comment: you mean that LinearLayout(mail_read_header) inside WebView(mail_read_contents)? @AndresCardenasPardo

Comment: I say to try create LinearLayouts inside like space, that linear you create, put them android:weight

Comment: WebView extends `AbsoulteLayout` so can't adjust android:weight. I'm so sorry if I am misunderstanding

Comment: Try [WebViewClient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8005439/2591002)