# android webview taking up full screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a header "54dp" and a the rest of the activity be a WebView.

When I preview my activy in the "Graphical Layout" within eclips it looks good. But when run the application on the phone or emulator the webview takes up the entire screen.

This is what the preview looks like and how I want it:

[image]

But this is what I see when I run the app:

[image]

This is what the layout xml looks like:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/page_background"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/Layout_Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/container_header"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHeaderLogo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_header_logo_description"
            android:src="@drawable/header_logo" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

## SOLUTION:

in the activity java file I had this:

```java
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
setContentView(browser);
```

When I should have had this:

```java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_web_view);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the WebView's height to 0dp and its weight to 1.

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Comment: I spoke too soon... This should work. But as soon as i put in the code to load a page... it takes the entire screen. Very strange.

Comment: Figured it out... thanks! Giving you the credit because using weight fills it up best. I'm posting an update to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of some redirect, which open the Browser application, you can use

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

to load the redirection in your `WebView`. I've just had the same issue and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382258/326849).

Answer (score 1):

change this manually in xml for web view

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

as

```
    android:layout_height="200dp"
```

And if it works change the height parameter as you like in the "android:layout_height"

Comment: Same thing... It's ignoring the layout_height when I run it. I have no idea why.

Comment: In your Imageview xml you have set width as 0dp change it to-->android:layout_width="200dp" and check

Comment: When I do that it eclipse says "Use a layout_width of 0dip instead of 200dp for better performance" And I get the same results... webview fullscreen. :/

Comment: I figured it out.. there was no way of you knowing because I did not show my code behind! (next time I will even if I think it doesn't have anything related) +1 for the effort.