# WebView in part of screen (not entire screen)

Tags: android, android-webview

In Android is it possible to put a `WebView` in only part of the screen?  If so, what is the XML to do it?  I want to create a table with HTML if possible that is scrollable as it could contain a lot of rows of data. Thanks for any info.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:onClick="startDataGathering"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:onClick="stopDataGathering"
        android:text="Stop" />

    <!-- want a webview here to cover rest of screen -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382188/how-to-set-webview-as-non-fullscreen

Comment: First, you need to be more specific about what you are trying to do. What part of the screen do you want the `WebView` on, and how much? Relative size? Static size? Second, you need to show some effort on your part, this isn't a code shop...

Comment: what-have-you-tried/got-code?

Comment: Check edit.  I want to have it take up the remaining part of the screen at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WebView can be placed and displayed like any other View. From your code, I'm guessing you want the WebView below the two buttons, with startButton at the top left and stopButton at the top right, with a gap between the two buttons.

In your case, since both buttons are presumably the same height, just tell the WebView to be below the startButton, since your stopButton is relative to it as well:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/startButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RelativeLayout you can use simple LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="startDataGathering"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="stopDataGathering"
            android:text="Stop" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The difference is that this layout contains WebView below buttons? And this is exactly what you asked for?